# Passing virtual keyboard inputs to LibreOffice

Tags: python-2.7, libreoffice

I'm trying to build a python script to run a LibreOffice Impress slide show, and change slides with the help of virtual keyboard inputs. I'm launching the slide show as a sub-process and using the Python uinput linux kernel module (www.tjjr.fi/sw/python-uinput/) to provide a virtual 'enter-key' input. How do I pass this input to LibreOffice? The platform used is ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Which platform do you use? Windows? Linux?

Comment: The platform used is linux.